# How to solve the equation of a hyperbola given only its axes of symmetry and x-intercept

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> The graph of a hyperbola with equation $y=f(x)$ has the following properties:
>
> - The equations of the axes of symmetry are $y=x-1$ and $y=-x+3$
> - Passes through the point $(-2,0)$
>
> Determine $f(x)$

This is the question I need to answer. I know that to figure out the axes of symmetry I need to use the formulas $y=(x-p)+q$ and $y=-(x-p)+q$. However, how do I use this information to determine the equation of the hyperbola? I am assuming that I use the point $(-2,0)$ as the $y$ and $x$ values in the axes of symmetry to find the p and q values, but I do not know for sure if this is possible, because when I used graphing software to plot the hyperbola and axes of symmetry, the hyperbola cut through the opposite side of the axes of symmetry in order to pass the point $(-2,0)$. I believe this shouldn't happen and I am unfortunately struggling.

Comment: Notice that the slopes of the axes of symmetry are $1$ and $-1$ which are parallel to the hyperbola with graph $xy=1$. In general, hyperbolas with axes of symmetry the same as the hyperbola $xy=1$ have equations of the form $xy=c$ where either $c>0$ or $c<0$. Except that your two axes of symmetry do not intersect at $(0,0)$, but somewhere else. (You can find where they intersect by setting their equations equal and solving for first $x$ then $y$) So you are looking for an equation of the form $x-x_0,y-y_0)=c$. Use the given point $(-2,0)$ and the values the $(x_0,y_0)$ intersection to find c.

Comment: Now that I have told you how to work it on your own, someone will probably jump in and solve it for the points, but try to work it yourself before looking at someone else's solution.

Comment: I meant to write $(x-x_0)(y-y_0)=c$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given its lines of symmetry as $y=x-1$ and $y=-x+3$, the hyperbola's centre is where these two lines intersect: $x-1=-x+3$ implies $x=2$ and $y=1$, so the centre is $(2,1)$. Since these lines have slopes $+1$ and $-1$, the hyperbola is rectangular and is given by the equation
$$(x-2)(y-1)=a$$
To find the value of $a$, plug in the coordinates of $(-2,0)$, the point known to be on the hyperbola:
$$(-2-2)(0-1)=4$$
Therefore the full equation is $(x-2)(y-1)=4$. Solving for $y$:
$$y-1=\frac4{x-2}$$
$$y=\frac4{x-2}+1$$